# Can I upload the WebRTC audio blob object with the file input element as normal file but without download it?

Tags: javascript, php, audio, upload, webrtc

Thank you so much for viewing my question.
Now I use WebRTC to record an audio and I finally got a blob object to which I can use JavaScript code to link the src of an audio element and play it as normal audio file.
Here my question comes.
Can I use the JavaScript code to make the blob pointed to an input element so that I can upload it as upload normal file with simple PHP code in the server side?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [**RecordRTC**](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/) to capture **audio**-blob; and **POST** to nodejs server using XHR/**FormData**.

[Here is a demo](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC/RecordRTC-to-Nodejs) recording both audio/video streams individually; **POST**-ing them over nodejs server; which writes both files to disk. Additionally, nodejs server uses **ffmpeg** to *merge* audio/video files in single **webm** format.

You can try [PHP](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC/RecordRTC-to-PHP) and [ASP.NET MVC](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC/RecordRTC-to-ASPNETMVC) specific demos as well!

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried your demo and it works. But what confused me is that the src of the audio and the video elements emerged get wrong. For example, the src would be like:localhost/RecordRTC-to-PHP/index.htmluploads/152237253.webm. while it is supposed to be ....RecordRTC-to-PHP/uploads/*.webm . Thank you for your help again.